# Why length function does not work correct in R?

Tags: r

Following R code gives the cars which are in Type Small. But length function returns 6 instead of 13. Why is that?

```
> fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",]            

            row.names Weight  Disp. Mileage     Fuel  Type
1      Eagle.Summit.4     30   0.97      33 3.030303 Small
2       Ford.Escort.4     28 114.00      33 3.030303 Small
3      Ford.Festiva.4     23   0.81      37 2.702703 Small
4       Honda.Civic.4     27   0.91      32 3.125000 Small
5     Mazda.Protege.4     29 113.00      32 3.125000 Small
6    Mercury.Tracer.4     27   0.97      26 3.846154 Small
7     Nissan.Sentra.4     27   0.97      33 3.030303 Small
8    Pontiac.LeMans.4     28   0.98      28 3.571429 Small
9     Subaru.Loyale.4     27 109.00      25 4.000000 Small
10     Subaru.Justy.3     24   0.73      34 2.941176 Small
11   Toyota.Corolla.4     28   0.97      29 3.448276 Small
12    Toyota.Tercel.4     25   0.89      35 2.857143 Small
13 Volkswagen.Jetta.4     28 109.00      26 3.846154 Small

> length(fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",])

[1] 6
```

Comment: Is it returning the number of columns instead of number of rows?

Comment: You've got rows and columns, so length doesn’t make sense. Try nrow()

Comment: Worth noting that this is very difficult for a new user to figure why this is so: `?length` says 'For vectors (including lists) and factors the length is the number of elements', but this is not informative if you don't realize that data frames inherit from lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`length` gives in this case the number of columns in the data frame. You can instead use `nrow` or `ncol` to get the number of rows or number of columns respectively:

```
nrow(fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",])
```

Another example using iris dataset:

```
> d = head(iris)
> d
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> nrow(d)
[1] 6
> ncol(d)
[1] 5
> dim(d)
[1] 6 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might help to give a bit of an explanation as to thy your getting your result. Your asking the length of the data.frame not the vector. Since the data.frame has 6 columns that explains your result.

this asks for the vector specifically:

```
length(fuel.frame$Type[fuel.frame$Type=="Small"])
```

and so does this:

```
length(fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",][,1])
```

or use `nrow` instead of `length` as already suggested.

Comment: Or `length(fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",1])` to combine the two `[` operations in your second example.

Comment: length(fuel.frame$Type[fuel.frame$Type=="Small"]) this shows where my fault is

Comment: 1. length(fuel.frame$Type[fuel.frame$Type=="Small"]) or 
2. length(fuel.frame[fuel.frame$Type=="Small",1]) give the result that I expect. For the second option we can use numbers from 1 to 6 as column number for my data. 

this explains why my code didnt give the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Or in this case `sum(fuel.frame$Type == "Small")`